# react-native login screen - error when login button is pressed with empty login fields

Tags: react-native, authentication, null

I have a simple login screen that asks for an email and password.

[Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp6iK.jpg)

If the "Sign In" button is pressed and both of the fields are blank I get this error: "null is not an object (evaluating'_this.state.Email')"

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwMDw.jpg)

Here is the code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Button, ScrollView, AsyncStorage, Alert } from 'react-native';
import colors from '../config/colors';
import { TextInput } from '../components/TextInput';

class SignIn extends Component {
    signIn = () => {

        const {Email} = this.state;
        const {Password} = this.state;

        fetch('http://192.168.1.3/Restaurant_App/php/sign_in.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application.json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
            email: Email,
            password: Password,
            })
        }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            if (responseJson == Email) {
                Alert.alert(responseJson);
                AsyncStorage.setItem('email', Email);
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Search');
            } else {
                Alert.alert(responseJson);
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: colors.background }}>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Email..."
                        onChangeText={Email => this.setState({Email})}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Password..."
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        onChangeText={Password => this.setState({Password})}
                    />
                </ScrollView>
                <Button
                    onPress={() => this.signIn()}
                    title="Sign In"
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
export default SignIn;
```

I would like it to be so that if the "Sign In" button is pressed with empty fields, I won't get this error. Instead, there should be an alert saying "Please fill in all fields." or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do some validation checks before making the fetch request.

You could do something like this

```
signIn = () => {

    const {Email, Password} = this.state;
    if(!this.checkDetails(Email, Password) {
      // you could show an alert here, but it is not great UX, 
      // you should show your user where they have gone wrong, 
      // by making style changes, a red border around the TextInput, 
      // text explaining what has gone wrong.
      return;
    }

    fetch('http://192.168.1.3/Restaurant_App/php/sign_in.php', {
        ...
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        ...
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
};

checkDetails = (Email, Password) => {

  // check that it is a valid email address
  // this is a regex that I have used in the past to check email addresses.
  const emailIsValid = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(Email);

  // if the password has a minimum length then you should use that rather than 0
  this.setState({emailIsValid, passwordIsValid: Password.length > 0});
  if (emailIsValid && Password.length > 0) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Using these new state values for the email and password being valid you could set additional styles and error text beside the fields that are wrong or missing.

```
<TextInput
   placeholder="Email..."
   onChangeText={Email => this.setState({Email})}
   styles={this.state.emailIsValid ? styles.validEmail : styles.invalidEmail}
 />
 {!this.state.emailIsValid && <Text>Please input a valid email</Text>}
 <TextInput
   placeholder="Password..."
   secureTextEntry={true}
   onChangeText={Password => this.setState({Password})}
   styles={this.state.passwordIsValid ? styles.validPassword : styles.invalidPassword}
 />
 {!this.state.passwordIsValid && <Text>Please input a valid password</Text>}
```

Don't for get to set up your styles for the different states.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  validEmail: {},
  validPassword: {},
  invalidEmail: {},
  invalidPassword: {}
});
```

You'll probably want to add initial state values for the emailIsValid and passwordIsValid so that they are set to true so that the correct styles are shown. Also you should define initial state for the Email and Password.

Add a constructor to your class

```
constructor (props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       Email: '',
       Password: '',
       emailIsValid: true,
       passwordIsValid: true
   }
}
```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: This worked, and I agree about the alert not being good for UX, so thank you for showing a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do at the top of your sign in function something like this:

```
If(this.state.email.length === 0  || this.state.password.length === 0) {
alert(“please complete the fields”);
return;}
```